# Spring 4 Using @Lazy and @Resource annotations together

Tags: spring, spring-4

I would like to lazy load a resource within a lazy loaded configuration class. it seems that it is not currently possible with Spring 4.1.

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
public class ModificationConfiguration {

    @Resource(name="modProps")
    @Lazy
    Map<String, String> props;


    @Bean
    Map<String, String> modProps(){
       ...
    }
}
```

from the Spring documentation

> In addition to its role for component initialization, the `@Lazy` annotation may also be placed on
>   injection points marked with `@Autowired` or `@Inject`. In this context, it leads to the injection
>   of a lazy-resolution proxy.

It seems natural to also want this available with `@Resource` as I can't use `@Autowired` on a `Map<String, String>`.  Without the `@Lazy` being available on `@Resource` the `modProps()` bean is created straight away.

Is there a technical reason why it is not currently possible to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier` instead... Also having an injection point and the bean in the same class seems a bit weird to me... Then just make the bean method lazy...

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't think you can autowire a map in that way see <a href="https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12180 " > Autowired does not work for target bean of type Collection</a> response from Juergen Hoeller that recommends Resource as alternative.  I believe modProps() should be lazy as Lazy already appears as class annotation.

Comment: Still what you are appearing to do seems just wrong to me. A lazy class which contains the definition for the bean auto wiring itself lazily… That for some reason feels wrong on way too many levels.

Comment: The lazy configuration is for a module of the application which only exists and is wholey activated dependent on some runtime choices.  When other lazy beans in the configuration are activated they use the  props map.  Accessing the resource in turn should activate the modProps bean to do the processing required to produce the map  resource. I simply  want to avoid activating the bean that supplies the resource until the resource is used. Please elaborate on why this causes you unease.

Comment: You have a lazy bean which in turn creates its own bean which is also injected to that same instance? Judging from your description what you actually want to use is bean profiles which you are trying now to hack around. Also you are on Spring 4.1 which has a new feature for conditional beans (this was inspired and elaborated by Spring Boot) you can make beans conditionally loaded based on whatever you like (you can define your own rules). So I would suggest you take a look in either of the 2 options.